# How to avoid 'The value 'DynamicObject<JSFunction> cannot be passed from one context to another' error

Tags: karate

I am facing an issue that I have come across before that has increasingly become more and more problematic.

I have a scenario where I am declaring a variable in the background and setting it equal to a call to a javascript method that has been defined in a secondary feature file that houses other javascript methods.

This variable is then part of a table that is being passed to another secondary feature file that is doing further processing.

When this scenario is run, when the call comes to that variable, I get the following error: "The value 'DynamicObject@70ecb7f6' cannot be passed from one context to another"

If I change the variable in the background to a static value such as a random string, this error does not occur.

I apologize in advance since I can't be precise in this question and cannot set up reproducible steps. I tried to create generic steps, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: if you are not on 1.4.0, upgrade. else you have to replicate this for us to investigate